# ampersand issues

Tags: php, mysql

I have a link stored in my database, lets say it's

```
http://somedomain.com/page.php?username=tom&surname=smith
```

When I bring this back to html, I get an xhtml error because of the `&`

How do I convert the `&` to an `&#38;`

Also, I have some links in the database which already have `&#38;` instead of `&`

So, how do I convert `&` when required, but not convert `&#38;` to `&#38;#38;`

Comment: Your "some links" are wrong and must be changed.  Do not store escaped text in a database.

Comment: You may use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), also, why you need to convert & to &#38.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't store escaped/encoded text. You never know what format the text will be required to be in when you retrieve it. If you store it URL-encoded, but you have to insert it into an HTML document,then you have to undo the url encoding and switch to HTML encoding. Which is a waste. Best to store it in 'raw' format and convert as needed at the time you need it.

Use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to escape/encode the XML/HTML metacharacters prior to inserting into your XML document.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data has already been stored in the database like this before I was made in-charge of the mess...

Comment: In that, case it's a onetime fix-up to de-quote the urls.

Comment: How would I do a one time fix up?

Comment: grab the 'bad' rows from the database, fix up the bad quoted values in php, stuff them back into the database. Probably all of about 10 lines of PHP, worst case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be do replace all `&#38;` to `&`, and then all `&` to `$#38;`, such as

```
$content = str_replace("&#38;", "&", $content);
$content = str_replace("&", "$#38;", $content);
```

But you should not store data like that in your database.